# Does 'fever' share an etymology with 'fervent, fervid, or fervour'?

Tags: etymology

The [ODO entry for 'fervent'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fervent) recommends to:

> Compare with fervid and fervour.

I did read [Etymonline's entry for 'fever'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fever&searchmode=none) which doesn't explicitly answer this, but I think that I'd need to know rare linguistic variants to compare the etymologies and 'read between the lines' ?

Footnote: [This article on the 'fiery' US TV series 'House of Cards'](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150304-is-house-of-cards-worth-watching)  inspired this question.

Comment: The OED says that _fever_ comes from a common root for 'fever' in Latin and Germanic; _fervor_ comes from a Latin verb meaning 'boil', and _fervid_ comes from a different Latin verb meaning 'to glow'.

Comment: @John: but *to boil*, *to glow*, and *to be feverous* all have in common the notion of being hot, their Latin roots are very similar, and I think it would be very surprising if they didn't all come from the same root in one of the not-too-far-removed ancestors of Latin.

Comment: The AHD says they all come from [the PIE root *bhreu-](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=bhreu-), so your hypothesis is confirmed, @Peter.

Comment: @JohnLawler The link you provide doesn't list "fever". According to Wiktionary, we are dealing with two different PIE roots here.

Answer (score 2):

No. According to Wiktionary, "fever" [can be traced](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/febris#Latin) to the Proto-Indo-European root [*dʰegʷʰ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eg%CA%B7%CA%B0-). "Febrile" would be a cognate.

"Fervo(u)r"/"fervid" [can be traced to a different](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferveo#Latin) Proto-Indo-European root, [*bʰrewh-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/b%CA%B0rewh%E2%82%81-).

And while they have meanings that touch on similar things (being hot), these are two different roots. Thus, there is no shared etymology.